# Why does the RenderSize of a Grid stay the same in all three of these cases?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

        <!--The following code snippets go here-->

</Window>
```

### Example 1

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="200" Height="100" Background="Green">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"></ScaleTransform>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Actual:**

```
myGrid.RenderSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 200

myGrid.DesiredSize
{600,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 600
```

**Expected:**

```
myGrid.RenderSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 600

myGrid.DesiredSize
{600,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 600
```

### Example 2

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="200" Height="100" Background="Green">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"></ScaleTransform>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Actual:**

```
myGrid.RenderSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 200

myGrid.DesiredSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 200
```

**Expected:**

```
myGrid.RenderSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 600

myGrid.DesiredSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 200
```

### Example 3

```
<Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="200" Height="100" Background="Green"></Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

**Actual:**

```
myGrid.RenderSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 200
myGrid.DesiredSize
{200,100}
    Height: 100
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 200
```

**Expected:**

Not sure, if Viewbox uses `RenderTransform` then I would expect `myGrid.RenderSize.Width` to be `600` and `myGrid.DesiredSize.Width` to be `200`, otherwise if Viewbox uses `LayoutTransform` then I would expect `myGrid.RenderSize.Width` and `myGrid.DesiredSize.Width` to be `600`.

---

I am basing my expected results  based on the following layout process stages:

1. LayoutTransform
2. Measure - DesiredSize of each element is computer here
3. Arrange - Position of child elements within their parents is determined
4. RenderTransform
5. Render - RenderSize is computer here, elements are rendered to the screen

#### Questions:

- Does Viewbox apply RenderTransform or LayoutTransform?
- How does RenderTransform change the element such that RenderSize dimensions do not change?
- For example 1, why is Rendered Width is 200, even though LayoutTransform is applied to `myGrid` and the Desired with is 600?

Thank you in advance.